# Transferring a randomly generated DB key between GET and POST

Tags: python, flask, redis

I'm having trouble with the POST section of the code below. I've come to the conclusion that after the form is sent from login the key variable is being reloaded and the integer change to no longer always match for the logic. But for some reason if i print `riddle` and `dbanswer` to the terminal, it always works.

I'm new to Python and Flask and am not sure if there's a way to fix this bug in my code by re-arranging it or using some sort of redirect to process the GET and POST separately so that the key is fixed between the two.

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def HomePage():

    key = random.randint(1,3)

    riddle = con.get("riddle:%i" %key)
    dbanswer = con.get("riddle:%i:answer" %key)

    # print(riddle)
    # print(dbanswer)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("login.html", riddle = riddle)


    elif request.method =="POST":
        answer = request.form['answer']
        if answer == dbanswer:
            return render_template("welcome.html")
        else:
            return render_template("login.html", riddle = riddle)

    else:
        return "<h2>Invalid request</h2>"
```

Comment: The stateless nature of HTTP dictates that the server won't remember the dbanswer without some help.  Look into storing the key in either a session or application context.

Comment: If you want to use sessions, you can store your random key in a global dictionary and make the session ids dictionary keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the key in the form.

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('login.html', riddle=riddle, riddle_id=key)
```

Then in your `login.html` form, use that value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="riddle_id" value="{{ riddle_id }}"/>
```

Now when you `POST` that form to your view, you can grab it to complete the circle:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    answer = request.form['answer']
    riddle_id = request.form['riddle_id']
    if answer == con.get("riddle:%i:answer" % riddle_id):
        return render_template("welcome.html")
```